# google developer console API library is only opening to a blank screen?

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-developers-console

for a project I need to use the google API to have a google sheets that a python script can read and write to from any computer, but the google developer console isn't working as intended as far as I know.

-I've opened the website https://console.cloud.google.com/

-I've made a project

-selected the project

-opened "api services" and then "library"

-its loaded a blank page rather than the normal page I've seen load on every tutorial.

I've tried a second project and the exact same thing happened, none of the tutorials mention another step being needed before opening the library, not sure what's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem..May you can try an other Browser that works a while for me to see the content

Comment: this works but is not ideal as using multiple browsers is an inconvenience. my original browser, that it wasn't working on for me, was chrome as well so this doesn't make sense as googles own developer console requires a different companies browser to function